# Symfony2 Finding Duplicate Rows and Summing Another Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2 and doctrine to grab all the duplicate rows and how many times they appear. That part I have down. Now, each of these rows has a qty field as well. What I am wanting to do is run my query and show how many times the duplicate row appears as well as sum the qty field for each of these rows:

My database table looks like this:

```
  id | sku  | qty
  ----------------------
  1   A      1
  2   B      1
  3   A      3
  4   A      5
  5   A      1
  6   A      1
  7   B      2
  8   A      1
  9   A      1
```

Here is my initial query that grabs all duplicate rows:

```
 SELECT  o, count(o.id) as cnt
 FROM    WIC\APIBundle\Entity\FBAOrderHistory o
 GROUP BY o.sku HAVING cnt > 1 order by cnt desc
```

It outputs this:

```
  id | sku  | cnt
  ----------------------
  1   A      7
  2   B      2
```

But what I want is this:

```
  id | sku  | cnt  | qty
  ----------------------
  1   A      7      13
  2   B      2      3
```

Does anyone know how to do this. Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM()`

```
 SELECT  o, count(o.id) as cnt ,sum(o.qty) as 
 FROM    WIC\APIBundle\Entity\FBAOrderHistory o
 GROUP BY o.sku HAVING cnt > 1 order by cnt desc
```

[**Using DQL**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html#using-dql)

### [Mysql Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d83d7/3)